# Custom resource/claim not being returned in "userinfo"

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm trying to add some custom claims to my IdentityServer4 flow, but I can't get them to show up in the `/userinfo` endpoint.

I'm only using "in memory" configuration for now, so in this I have created a new `IdentityResource` with my custom scope:

```cs
new IdentityResource {
    DisplayName = "My Custom Resource",
    Name = "mycustom",
    UserClaims = new List<string> {
        "mycustom.myvalue"
    }
}
```

And I've set my client to be able to use this:

```cs
new Client {
    AllowedScopes = {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        "mycustom"
    }
}
```

Then, whenever a login is successful, I do the following to sign in the user before redirecting back to `/authorize/callback`

```cs
await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(
    "provider",
    "providerUserID",
    "subjectID",
    "name"));
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
    "subject",
    "name",
    new AuthenticationProperties(),
    new Claim("mycustom.myvalue", "987654321"));
```

Now, I can do a full `authorize` flow with `?scope=openid+mycustom`, but when I make the call to the `userinfo` endpoint, it does not return `mycustom.myvalue`

I'm probably only missing some minor detail, but I can't for the life of me figure out what... so what am I missing to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because when you add your claim via `HttpContext.SignInAsync(..., new Claim("mycustom.myvalue", "987654321"))` it is only retained whenever the user is actually present and the `ClaimsPrincipal` is created through the cookie authentication.

Because you are doing the roundtrip back to `/userinfo` it will only give you claims that the default `IProfileService` would normally return and it can't possibly know about that extra claim.

Try adding this claim to one of the `TestUser` directly (if you are using in memory users):

```
    public static List<TestUser> GetUsers()
    {
        return new List<TestUser>
        {
            new TestUser
            {
                SubjectId = "1",
                Username = "alice",
                Password = "password",

                Claims = new []
                {
                    new Claim("name", "Alice"),
                    new Claim("website", "https://alice.com"),
                    new Claim("mycustom.myvalue", "987654321")
                }
            }....
```

Comment: I'm not using in-memory-users, so I can't do it like this. Basically I'm authenticating with some 3rd party, and when it is complete I get some values from the third party and need to add those values to a claim that will be visible from `userinfo`. I considered an `IProfileService`, but this would not have enough information to call the 3rd party, so I would very much like to set these values as close to the redirect back to `authorize/callback`

Comment: Yeah, you can't do this then I think. You need to either put these claims inside the custom `UserStore` directly or implement custom `IProfileService`.

Comment: I looked into a custom `IProfileService` and noticed that the "mycustom.myvalue" is set in the `context.Subject.Claims` when accessing the token endpoint (`context.Caller == "ClaimsProviderAccessToken"`), but it is not set when accessing the userinfo endpoint. How "dirty" would it be to use `context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(new Claim[])` when token endpoint is being called to force the claim to be available during userinfo endpoint?

Comment: After adding the functionality described in the previous comment I can see that when requesting the userinfo endpoint, `context.Subject.Claims` does indeed contain `mycustom.myvalue`, but it is still not returned in userinfo. I guess I could always do another `context.IssuesClaims.AddRange()` to force it in, but this is where it becomes dirty :)

Comment: @GTHvidsten so you are observing exactly what I described in my answer as to why your custom claim is not going to be available on the callback to `/userinfo`. The `IProfileService` is there exactly for this extensibility reason, if you need to add custom user claims for some reason, then do it, dirty or not.

Comment: But why do you have to first add the custom claims in `/token`, then add them again in `/userinfo`? The "dirty" part is having to add the claims twice, and adding my own checks on `context.RequestedResources.IdentityResources` on whether they should be added or not. It would seem logical that when `context.Subject.Claims` contains a specific claim during `/userinfo`, and this claim is also part of the claims in the access token, then that value would be returned without having to add it manually.

Comment: @GTHvidsten because it's a different callback. The claims you create during `GetProfileData()` method in `IProfileService` are not retained anywhere other than the token, so basically the first time you get the token back with your extra claim, then you callback for `/userinfo` and you have to add them again if you want them again. Your own checks are fine as well, there are convenience methods I think `AddRequestedClaims()` or something. You should maybe try setting `AlwaysIncludeClaimsInToken` to true on the client configuration which will remove the need for `/userinfo` calls.

Comment: Just another observation I don't know if can be used: The `PersistedGrants` in the database has a `Data` column, which does indeed contain the custom claim added during the `SignInAsync()`. I'm just a bit surprised this data is not available during `/userinfo`